# Get particular dropdown in a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have multiple dropdown in a div. This is automatically generated. I have done that work. But i need to get the nth dropdown. Please help me to get this.

```
$('#show_label_categories')[1].find('select').each(function () {

});

<div id="show_label_categories">
  <select name="search_category" class="form-control parent">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1">Tutorials</option>
    <option value="2">Demos</option>
    <option value="3">Entertainment</option>
    <option value="4">Real Estate</option>
    <option value="5">Web Development</option>
    <option value="6">Browsers</option>
    <option value="43">Laptop</option>
    <option value="46">1</option>
  </select>
  <select name="search_category" class="form-control parent">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="12">PHP demos</option>
    <option value="13">jQuery demos</option>
  </select>
  <select name="search_category" class="form-control parent">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="36">Good Demos</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#show_label_categories select').eq(1)` or what @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:eq(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, so for the second `select`:

```
$('select:eq(1)');
```

`n` is the zero-based index.

An example to color it red:

```js
$('#show_label_categories select:eq(1)').css('color', 'red');
alert('Length: ' + $('#show_label_categories select:eq(1)').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show_label_categories">
  <select name="search_category" class="form-control parent">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1">Tutorials</option>
    <option value="2">Demos</option>
    <option value="3">Entertainment</option>
    <option value="4">Real Estate</option>
    <option value="5">Web Development</option>
    <option value="6">Browsers</option>
    <option value="43">Laptop</option>
    <option value="46">1</option>
  </select>
  <select name="search_category" class="form-control parent">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="12">PHP demos</option>
    <option value="13">jQuery demos</option>
  </select>
  <select name="search_category" class="form-control parent">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="36">Good Demos</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. $('#show_label_categories select:eq(1)').length it always return 0.

Comment: @RomiltonFernando that's because the `eq(1)` selects the *second* `select` - so `0` is the length of that one element.

Comment: sorry I misread - the length should be `1` @RomiltonFernando. I've edited the snippet so you can see the length. It will now show you an alert of `Length: 1`, not `0`. You must have typed something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$("#show_label_categories").children("select:nth(1)");
```